# In MySQL, what does this simple nested SELECT clause mean exactly?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the example from this [thread](https://leetcode.com/discuss/65549/a-simple-answer):

```
select (
  select distinct Salary from Employee order by Salary Desc limit 1 offset 1
)as second;
```

The `select(...) as second` looks confusing to me because I've never seen a query-set instead of column names can be used as the argument of `SELECT`..

Does anyone have ideas about how to understand nested `select` clause like this? Is there any tutorials about this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a subquery in the SELECT list of a query.

To get there, let's look at some other examples

```
SELECT t.id
     , 'bar' AS foo 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE ...
 LIMIT ...
```

'bar' is just a string literal that gets returned in every row (in a column named foo) in the resultset from the query.

Also, MySQL allows us to run a query *without* a FROM clause

```
SELECT 'fee' AS fum
```

We can also put a subquery in the SELECT list of a query. For example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , (SELECT r.id FROM resorts r ORDER BY r.id ASC LIMIT 1) AS id
  FROM mytable
 WHERE ...
 LIMIT ...
```

The query pattern you asked about is a SELECT statement without a FROM clause

And the only expression being returned is the result from a subquery.

For example:

```
 SELECT e.salary 
   FROM Employee e
  GROUP BY e.salary
  ORDER BY e.salary DESC
  LIMIT 4,1
```

If this query runs, it will return one column, and will return either one or zero rows. (No more than one.) This satisfies the requirements for a subquery used in a SELECT list of another query.

```
SELECT ( subquery ) AS alias
```

With that, the outer query executes. There's no FROM clause, so MySQL returns one row. The resultset is going to consist of one column, with a name of "alias".

For each row returned by the outer query, MySQL will execute the subquery in the SELECT list. If the subquery returns a row, the value of the expression in the SELECT list of the subquery is assigned to the "alias" column of the resultset. If the execution of the subquery doesn't return a row, then MySQL assigns a NULL to the "alias" column.